# renderToString is making every character of file lowercase, so not able to render, what to do to resolve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a script which reads reactjs file and then I render it into html using `renderToString`. But `renderToString` makes my component `className` and all other pascalCased imports into lowercase. Because of that I get this error:

> Invariant violation: Invalid tag: import react, {component} from 'react'
>   class app extends component {}

Here is the script:

```
const reactElement = require('react').createElement;
const ReactDomServer = require('react-dom/server');

const renderHTML = Component => {
  return ReactDomServer.renderToString(element(Component))
}
```

P.S. element(Component) is giving me an object as it should be. But once I pass it into `renderToString`, that's when it lowercase everything. How can I resolve this issue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are experiencing is really weird, I could reproduce it by importing and rendering a React component as plain text (assuming that the `reactElement()` and `element()` in your code are the same thing):

```
const renderHTML = component => {
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(reactElement(component));
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, './YourElement.js'), (err, data) => {
    const fileContent = data.toString('utf-8');
    const output = renderHTML(fileContent);
    res.end(output);
  });
});
```

Thus I got the same error (indeed it is converted to lower case):

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: const react = require('react');
```

It means that you are importing your components as a plain text.

Make sure to import all the React components as **JavaScript modules**:

```
const YourElement = require('./YourElement');
// or
import YourElement from './YourElement';
```

Thus the `renderToString()` will convert everything into HTML properly.

Comment: It indeed was the same problem you mentioned. Thanks for your help. Now I have working script. And sorry for element typo.